# spring tool suite 4 maven console no output

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite, m2e

spring tool suite version
[image: spring tool suite version]

maven console no output
[image]

maven config
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually can you check if you can switch to another console? The console output might be on a default one